# Powershell indirect expansion variable

Tags: bash, powershell, variables

We have bash indirect expansion variables as follows
${!variable}

Is there any equivalent syntax in powershell??
If no, is there any workaround?

Adding Example
$username_master="SomeValue"

$branch="master"

$name="username_"+$branch

$value=$($name) --> Here it should resolve $name -> username_master then should resolve $username_master -> "SomeValue".

Thus echo $value should output "SomeValue"

The same can be achieved in bash by ${!value} which outputs "SomeValue", how to achieve the same in powershell?

Thanks in advance

Comment: from what i can tell, you are talking about accessing the parameters passed to a function. if that is the case, then take a look at the following automatic variables - `$PSBoundParameters` & `$Args`. you may also want to look at `ValueFromRemainingArguments`. parameter attribute.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention, we can say in `bash` as:

```
a="hello"
ref="a"
echo "${!ref}"
```

which outputs:

```
hello
```

The equivalence in `PowerShell` will be:

```
$a = "hello"
$ref = [ref]$a
echo $ref.Value
```

which also outputs:

```
hello
```

I hope this is what you want.

**[EDIT]**

According to the OP's example, how about:

```
$username_master = "SomeValue"
$branch = "master"
$name = "username_" + $branch
Get-Variable -Name $name -valueOnly
```

which outputs:

```
SomeValue
```

You can also assign a variable to the result with:

```
$value = Get-Variable -Name $name -valueOnly
echo $value
```

yields:

```
SomeValue
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Lets Take this example
$username_master="SomeValue"
$branch="master"
$name="username_"+$branch --> here after it resolves to username_master it should fetch the value of $username_master to $name

echo $name should output "SomeValue"

Could you please suggest a solution?? Thanks

Comment: @vinuvizal Thank you for the response. I've updated my answer by adding a solution for your example. BR.

Comment: Thanks! Tested it working perfectly fine :)

Comment: @vinuvizal Thanks for the immediate testing and feedback. Good to know it works. BR.